# Why my asp.net page is not showing styles I set

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a simple web form and have the back ground set to AppWorkspace and it displays the background as white. As far as font goes it set those right butt it wont show any color? Have any idea why I have look up different things about the css not working but nothing indicates there is a problem. How can I fix this to make my color show up. I am not sure what to provide so I am providing what I have that uses color.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="background-color:AppWorkspace">
<div style="background-color:AppWorkspace" runat="server">
```

These are suppose to set the colors but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: And what color "AppWorkspace" is? o.o

Comment: @Buzinas it's grey one of the many shades of gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing something in a style tag instead

```
<style type="text/css">
form{
background-color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Or use the style attribute in the code behind

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. Why does it not show my background color only on the div tag does it show it? Replaced both that I posted above.

Comment: the form needs something in it to show the color, try height: 500px

Comment: If this is the most stressful thing you have to deal with, I want your job lol

Comment: No not by far just had a brain lapse, lol. No one really to ask so thanks!